# file_put_contents auto increment duplicate int value in php?

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have small code.

total_request.txt is text file have content value =1

```
$file = 'total_request.txt';
$count = file_get_contents( $file );
echo $a = $count + 1;  
file_put_contents( $file, $a );
```

code output value: 2

but file total_request.txt have content 3. I want to automatically increment 1 when running this file php.

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What do you mean? If the file doesn't exist, it will be created, with value 1. If not, it will be increased by 1, and the output will match the content of the file... what exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie He's saying that the file goes from 1 to 3 instead of from 1 to 2. I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: Is this code inside a function or something and is getting executed twice? Is there any way for you to tell? Could you possibly try appending the contents temporarily instead of overwriting them - [`FILE_APPEND`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)?

Comment: Aha. No, can't reproduce either. It works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to open a file in append mode:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');//opens file in append mode  
fwrite($fp, ' this is additional text ');  
fwrite($fp, 'appending data');  
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I hope it may help you.

Regards.